# How to fix "type uint256 is not implicitly convertible to type address"?

Tags: solidity

I understand the error is because items is a mapping type that maps an address to an struct of type S_Item, and that the itemIndex variable is of type uint and is not of type address which I passed to items[itemIndex]...

How can I work around this issue? This code is from udemy course and the instructors have not replied yet...I really appreciate your help. Thanks!!

[image: sourcecode]
[image: errors]

Comment: In the future please copy/paste your code into a code block, it helps a ton being able to move it into an IDE and test whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error is in the mapping declaration. It should map uint to S_Item, not address.

Comment: I've tried that already, I still get the same errors on the emit lines

Comment: the issue seems to be with (items[_itemIndex]._state)); on the emit state lines.

Comment: change the uint _step in the SupplyChainStep event to SupplyChainState _step

Comment: And it will be great, if you post code snippets in the future instead of pictures. It would help others to execute and debug your code